# Public class inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

I have a public class and I'm trying to reference it in another project. It has a constructor:

```
namespace Stuff
{
    struct Vector
    {
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }

        public Vector (double ex, double why, double zee) 
        {
            this.x = ex;
            this.y = why;
            this.z = zee;
        }
```

...

and I keep getting the `inaccessible due to protection level` error.

This is how I'm referencing it in another project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Stuff;

namespace ProjectileMotion
{
    class Projectile
    {
        private Vector acceleration = new Vector(0, 0, -9.8); //the acceleration is a vector now.
```

...

The class 'Vector' is in a project called 'stuff' - it needs a better name.

Comment: declare the `Vector` struct as public and try again

Comment: well it clearly is not `public`

Comment: You have structure not class and it's not public. To make it public add `public struct Vector`

Comment: You need to replace `struct Vector` with `public struct Vector`. As is, `Vector` will only be available within the same DLL, since the default accessor is `internal`.

Comment: By default, any class or struct definition without an access modifier is internal, not public.

Answer (score 7):

You need do define your `struct` as `public`.

```
public struct Vector { ... }
```

Only because the constructor is public does not mean that the class/structure is also public.

With your current code the `struct` is only accessable within the containing assembly as the default access-modifier is `internal`. However within that assembly the class is visible everywhere.